# Application of cronR in Shiny App scheduled task

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to schedule a daily task to scrap and calculate price.

[image: cronR : Add scheduled task]

```
> cronR:::cron_rstudioaddin()
Loading required namespace: miniUI
Loading required namespace: shinyFiles

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5145
Warning in normalizePath(input$rscript_repository, winslash = "/") :
  path[1]="/cloud/project/Q": No such file or directory
RscriptRepository /cloud/project/Q does not exist, make sure this is an existing directory without spaces
Adding cronjob:
---------------

## cronR job
## id:   job_a8c93b03178d613ed999810c61baa9c1
## tags: forex
## desc: Scraping data for algorithmic calculation.
0 0 * * * /opt/R/3.4.4/lib/R/bin/Rscript '/cloud/project/Q1App2/global.R'  >> '/cloud/project/Q1App2/global.log' 2>&1
```

Below is my script for reproducible task...

```
suppressWarnings(require('cronR'))
suppressWarnings(require('xts'))
suppressWarnings(require('quantmod'))
suppressWarnings(require('lubridate'))

fx <- c('EURUSD=X', 'JPY=X', 'GBPUSD=X', 'CHF=X', 'CAD=X', 'AUDUSD=X')
wd <- c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')

#'@ if(now('GMT') == today('GMT')) {
## https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD=X?p=AUDUSD=X
## Above link prove that https://finance.yahoo.com using GMT time zone.  
if(weekdays(today('GMT'))%in% wd) {
  for(i in seq(fx)) {
    getSymbols(fx[i], from = (today('GMT') - 1) %m-% years(1), 
               to = (today('GMT') - 1))
  }
  rm(i)
}
```

### Reference

- [run task in background in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224109/run-task-in-background-in-shiny-app)
- [Deploy Shiny App with a scheduled script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128845/deploy-shiny-app-with-a-scheduled-script)
- [ReactiveTimer with if statement R-Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152855/reactivetimer-with-if-statement-r-shiny/47218602#47218602)
- [R plumber on Linux Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218743/r-plumber-on-linux-server)
- [bnosac/cronR](https://github.com/bnosac/cronR)